# Questions repeating on consecutive pages

Tags: discussion, support

The scenario is like this: I click the *Questions* button and select the "newest" tab to see the latest questions. I have set it to show 50 questions per page. On reaching the end of the page, I click next. On the next page, I notice that some of the questions that I had seen earlier are again listed repeatedly. Say when I go to the fourth page, some of the questions I saw in the third page are seen. Is this expected behavior? I am using the [Chrome](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Chrome) browser.

Comment: why would you want to read ALL the questions? Use favorite tags instead

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Is this expected behavior?

New questions came in between you getting to the bottom of the page and going to the next one, pushing some of those in the bottom to the next page by the time you had gotten to it.

Comment: Is there any easy way to read all the questions without missing any?

Comment: @user814064 All 5.7 million of them?

Comment: All the recent ones --in order.

Comment: @user814064 - How are you **missing** any if you are seeing the same ones a couple of times? Surely that is the **opposite** of missing.

Comment: On Clicking the next page user dosent expect to see the same questions on the next page.  A user interface is well-designed when the program behaves exactly how the user thought it would.- Joel Spolsky

(http://www.joelonsoftware.com/uibook/chapters/fog0000000057.html)

Comment: @Martin.kv Doing that would require remembering the current state of every single question in the entire site *for every user* so that when you go to the next page it knows what that page looked like at the item you first loaded the "questions" tab.  That's prohibitively expensive, to the point where it's just simply not even *possible*.

Comment: Ctrl/shift click a couple of the pages and move between the browser tabs/windows. Remembering the tab state would be a lot of work for very little gain (although not necessarily as much work as Servy makes it sound like).

Comment: If you see the same questions, how hard is it to click the next page again?

Comment: @Juhana For views sorted on "newest" it's not so bad because you can just remember the date of the oldest question on the page.  For "active" that doesn't work, as any number of the pages that would have been on the page may have been updated.  For "votes" you need to take into consideration that the score of any given question can go up or down by any amount, making this behavior on that view virtually impossible, as there are almost no optimizations that can be made.

Answer (score 0):

It works as a **STACK**.

Say if there are *400 recent questions* in *50-50 pieces*. Now, if you take the *first 50* and at the *end of the first 50 you move to the second 50*, and if there are already *30 new questions*, so you will get *30 old questions* on the second page.

> You can't go without it. What else can you do?

Just use a different tab. Let's decide you want to read the latest 100, 200, or 500 questions, so go with that. There is a maximum of a 50 question per page.

> Select your latest four pages (if you choose 200), and then open in different
>   tabs and then you can read all your selected questions which all are
>   the latest and you won't wonder about the repetition too.